# Stored procedures and sqlsrv_num_rows - cursor error?

Tags: php, sql-server

Is there a way to use sqlsrv_num_rows() with stored procedures?

Basically when i try to use this function I receive one of these errors, depending on the cursor i supply:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => IMSSP [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP [1] => -50 [code] => -50 [2] => This function only works with statements that have static or keyset scrollable cursors. [message] => This function only works with statements that have static or keyset scrollable cursors. ) )
```

or

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 01000 [SQLSTATE] => 01000 [1] => 16954 [code] => 16954 [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Executing SQL directly; no cursor. [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Executing SQL directly; no cursor. ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 01S02 [SQLSTATE] => 01S02 [1] => 0 [code] => 0 [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]Cursor type changed [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]Cursor type changed ) )
```

I've spent a bit of time trying to search for a solution to this issue, but no luck.

How can i get the row count from a stored procedure using SqlSrv?  Would i have to manually loop through the results and $count++; I would like to avoid that.  Or, is there some way I could change the actual stored procedure to include the cursor?  I'm not very familiar with cursors, so I don't really know if that is a solution or not.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see this: [sqlsrv_num_rows() with stored procedures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee376931%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)  doesn't seem like there is much other than work arounds.

you could capture the @@ROWCOUNT within the procedure and return it as an OUTPUT parameter.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE YourProc
(
    @param1 int
   ,@param2 varchar(5)
   ,@rowCountOf int OUTPUT
)
AS

SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ...  --returns result set
SET @rowCountOf=@@ROWCOUNT     --set output variable to be the row count
return 0
GO
```

or you could use `sp_executesql` instead as described in the above link.